# Оптимизация html-страниц для пользователя

Tags: html, веб-программирование, yii2

Есть лендинг на yii2 с возможностью оставить коментарии. К каждому можно оставить еще коментарий. Загрузка 20 последних, далее подгрузка аяксом по клику.

Вопрос: Есть ли смысл создавать форму для каждого коментария и ответа к нему, если изначально форма спрятана и видна только после клика.

Рассматриваю идею создать одну глобальную форму, и js'ом тянуть ее только после открытия формы в нужном месте.

Не являетса ли плохой практикой вывод форм к каждому? Форма примерно 60-70 строк.

Answer (score 0):

Не надо создавать для каждого. Надо сделать один view файл с формой и там где человек нажимает "ответ" просто её подгружать.